# I got a TypeError with my last function. How do I call them? Also, how do I find the totals and averages of everything? I'm lost

Tags: python

I previously asked on here about this payroll calculator I have been creating. I wrote it in Java but my professor doesn't want it in Java. I chose Python and now I'm struggling to translate my Java program.

I got a TypeError of unsupported operand type for -: 'function' and 'function'. From what I understand, I cannot subtract the defined functions. I would have to call them first. I have changed the code various times to fix the TypeError, and I still get the same error!! What can I do to fix this?

After fixing this, I would need to find the totals and averages of everything (pay, hours, gross pay, etc.). I didn't do that in my Java program. My brain is lost when figuring out how to code this. I have a chart with employee names, hours, and pay rates. Do I need to transfer that information in a spreadsheet and open the spreadsheet file within the python program?

Here is my code:

```
print('Hello')

percent = 15
tax_rate = percent / 100
print(tax_rate)

first_name = str(input('First Name: '))
last_name = str(input('Last Name: '))
print(last_name, ',', first_name)

pay_rate = float(input('Pay Rate: '))
total_hours = input('Hours Worked: ')
# regular hours = total hours if less than 40
# overtime = total hours - 40
regular_hours = 40
for regular_pay in total_hours:
    if float(total_hours) <= regular_hours:
        regular_pay = float(total_hours) * pay_rate
        print('Regular Pay: ', regular_pay)
for overtime_pay in total_hours:
    if float(total_hours) > regular_hours:
        overtime_pay = (float(total_hours) - float(40)) * 1.5 * pay_rate
        print('Overtime Pay: ',overtime_pay)


def gross_pay():
    return float(regular_pay) + float(overtime_pay)


print('Gross Pay: ', gross_pay())


def tax_amount():
    return (gross_pay) * tax_rate
# tax amount gross pay * tax rate


def net_pay():
    return gross_pay - tax_amount


print('Net Pay: ', net_pay())
# net pay = gross pay - tax amount
```

Comment: Think about the difference between e.g. `gross_pay` and `gross_pay()`.

Answer (score 2):

Concise version of the code. I assume that `total_hours` has a single number.

```
percent = 15
tax_rate = percent / 100
pay_rate = float(input('Pay Rate: '))
total_hours = float(input('Hours Worked: ')) # input a number

# regular hours = total hours if less than 40
# overtime = total hours - 40
regular_hours = min(40, total_hours)
regular_pay = regular_hours * pay_rate
overtime_hours = max(0, total_hours - 40)
overtime_pay = overtime_hours * 1.5 * pay_rate

# if you really want to use functions
def gross_pay():
    return regular_pay + overtime_pay

print('Gross Pay: ', gross_pay())

def tax_amount():
    return gross_pay() * tax_rate
# tax amount gross pay * tax rate

def net_pay():
    return gross_pay() - tax_amount()


print('Net Pay: ', net_pay())
# net pay = gross pay - tax amount 

# if you don't have a strong reason to use functions
gross_pay = regular_pay + overtime_pay
tax_amount = gross_pay * tax_rate
net_pay = gross_pay - tax_amount
print('Gross Pay: ', gross_pay)
print('Net Pay: ', net_pay)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're not calling the functions, fix the last lines as follows:

```
def tax_amount():
    return gross_pay() * tax_rate


def net_pay():
    return gross_pay() - tax_amount()
```

For me, the snippet then works fine. To call a function, use Function(), otherwise Python expects a variable which gives you the TypeError.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are making is calling the function without the brackets.

change:

```
def net_pay():
return gross_pay - tax_amount
```

to:

```
def net_pay():
return gross_pay() - tax_amount()
```